# OSX Cocoa Bad Instruction crash

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox, xcode6.1

I am developing an app (for like a year) and it works fine , when it comes to submitting to App Store -> all my problems started:

1)The app store would me to make my app to run in a sandbox(Why Apple ? Why !?).
It took like 2 days to understand why just toggling "ON" in capabilities doesn't make it...
etc ... in the end I somehow managed to convince my app to run in sandbox.

2)now the app passing the validation fine and can be submitted to the bloody App Store
However when I checked the app before the submitting I discovered that it simply don't want to work (running from Xcode or product).

It just crashes before it comes to `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions"
The crash itself is even more epic "thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subdued = 0x0)"

and I see a lot of assembly lines  -> from the comments inside the assembly I understood that the app tries to "Open" a sandbox , but then comes the bad instruction :( `ud2`

The stuck I see is:

```
_libseinit_initialize_once
0 _libsecinit_setup_secinitd_client
1 _libsecinit_initialize_once
2 _dispatch_client_callout
3 dispatch_once_f
4 libSystem_initializer
5 ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) ()
```

I think the rest are not relevant since they are all about some IMAGE loader  :/

lately I ensured that removing the `app sandbox` key or setting it to `NO` Resolves my Issue but if I do so i getting back to issue number 1

so I kinda stuck with an egg and a turkey problem :(

maybe some 1 knows any interesting workaround or solution to submit the bloody app to the mighty app store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what Apple document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html):

> OS X’s enforcement of container integrity impacts your development and
>   distribution cycle. This is because, in the course of creating and
>   distributing an app, the app is code signed using various signatures.
>   Here’s how the process works:
>
> Before you create a project, you obtain three code signing
>   certificates from Apple: a development certificate, a distribution
>   certificate, and (optionally) a Developer ID certificate. (To learn
>   how to obtain these code signing certificates, read App Distribution
>   Guide.) When used in conjunction with the corresponding private keys
>   from your keychain, these certificates form three separate digital
>   identities. For development and testing, you sign your app with your
>   development identity. When you submit a version to the app store, you
>   use your distribution identity. If you are distributing a version
>   outside the app store, you use your Developer ID identity.
>
> When the Mac App Store distributes your app, it is signed with an
>   Apple code signature. For testing and debugging, you may want to run
>   both versions of your app: the version you sign and the version Apple
>   signs. But OS X sees the Apple-signed version of your app as an
>   intruder and won’t allow it to launch: Its code signature does not
>   match the one expected by your app’s existing container.
>
> If you try to run the Apple-signed version of your app, you get a
>   crash report containing a statement similar to this:
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) The solution is to
>   adjust the access control list (ACL) on your app’s container to
>   recognize the Apple-signed version of your app. Specifically, you add
>   the designated code requirement of the Apple-signed version of your
>   app to the app container’s ACL.

Comment: You were right!! however I could do all that (ACL) I dk I didn't find any containers :( never mind , but I managed to run my app with a little lets call it workaround , reading the documentation I assumed that the ACL problem can occur only on local machine. (And I guess I was right) So I just sent the .app to my self by email , which is basically made `[*.app copy]` so I had a fresh .app out of the box and WOW I have to admit I was surprised , it WORKS !!!!!!! Thank you very much man!! give me ur address and a beer on me ;)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, and although Droppy's answer was correct, it doesn't really resolve the problem (at least, not for me).

After messing around a bit, I found that the reason I had this problem is that, (although I had disabled keychain sharing in 'Capabilities' in Xcode's project editor) I still had a keychain value added. Removing this, or completely disabling all app capabilities (yes, including sandbox) will solve this problem.

Hopefully, this saves someone some time in the future.